BBC horror film/ mini-series where writer is dicating memoirs of her feral orphaned childhood with her sister
OK, so I remember this was a BBC Drama/Horror program (could have been a film or 3 part type thing). It starts with an old woman who has had  successful career as a novelist, dictating her memoirs. 
She describes how her and her sister were orphaned in a big house and left to go feral (both ginger girls, possibly twins?). As they grow up various seemingly paranormal and sinister things happen, but the twist at the end is that there is a secret third sister we didn't know about who is causing the strange events. 
The program has the feel of a book adaptation, but I have no memory that it was. It was fairly recent (5 - 10 years ago), and shown in the UK.
